# app.post not working node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to node and I wanted to try a simple app.post but I can't get it to work. my app.js and index.jade code is shown below. I am trying to get my app to print "hi" to the console when I enter data in the form and press submit but this is not happening.

```
**app.js**

/**enter code here
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');

var routes = require('./routes');

var user = require('./routes/user');

var http = require('http');

var path = require('path');

var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

// all environments

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.favicon());

app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/users', user.list);

app.get('/george', function(req,res){
    res.send('This is the random george page');
    console.log("george");
});

app.get('/second', function(req,res){
    res.render('secondpage');
});

app.get('/act', function(request, response){
    console.log("hello");
});

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    console.log("hi");
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");





**index.jade**

extends layout

block content

  h1: a(href = 'second') George

  p Welcome to your demosite George


  form(method="post", action="/", name="act")

  p

  |Username

  input(type="text", name="user")

  p

  |Password

  input(type="text", name="pass")

  p

  input(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

Comment: Going along with Peter Lyon's question, does the browser even submit the form?  Like, does it just hit a different route handler or does it never make it back to the server?

Comment: it never made it back to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First guess is everything in your jade file after the `form` tag needs 2 more leading spaces indent to make sure the `input` tags end up nested inside the `form` tag in the HTML. Your express JS code looks like it should work then.